# How to build app using IPV6 IP Address in mobilefirst hybrid application?

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-studio

I'm using MobileFirst Platform Foundation 7.1 and IDE Eclipse Version Mars.2 Release (4.5.2).

While i'm building the app in Studio using an IPV6 Address it fails as follows:

> Incorrect MobileFirst server information: For input string:

[image]

Comment: Can you add an example of an IPv6 address you've used? You can change a number so that it won't match you real one...

Answer (score 0):

This error may happen if you are:

- incorrectly input the IPv6 address. For example like this: `https://[2001::db8:a0b:12f0::1]:21`.
- not enclosing the hostname in brackets, to keep it separate from the port number.

The following works: `https://[2001:db8:a0b:12f0::1]:21`